# Stack overflow and finding a base

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

```
public static float recursiveUse(float n2){

    if(n2 == 1)
        return 1;
    return recursiveUse(1/n2);      
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    float n2;
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
    n2 = stdin.nextFloat();

    System.out.print(1+(recursiveUse(n2)));
}

/*
    Write a Java application that uses recursion to compute the results of the following series:
    m(i) = 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + 1/5 … + 1/i

*/
```

I am currently having a problem with a stack overflow exception. I am pretty sure it is because base is in correct. My question is how do I find the base for the series just above. I have searched the site and I couldn't find anything applicable for this problem.

Thank you

Comment: Why do you expect that `1/(1/(1/(1/(1/.....n2)))...)` will be 1?

Comment: Honestly I have been working on this for so long that I don't really know now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `recursiveUse` method is entirely wrong. Look at it closely and you'll see that depending on input it will either never return, or only return `1`. The second point makes it useless, the first makes it go on until it overflows the stack.

You want to the sum of a portion of the harmonic series `1 + 1/2 + 1/3 … + /i`. Lets call our method `harmonicSum`:

```
public static double harmonicSum(int i)
{
  /* Code will go here */
}
```

Now for any given *i* where i ≥ 1 the result we should give will be the same as `1/i + harmonicSum(i - 1)`. E.g for `3` we have `1 + 1/2 + 1/3` which is `(1 + 1/2) + 1/3` which is `harmonicSum(2) + 1/3.

We need to have a point where we just stop and return an answer, but it's obvious that `harmonicSum(0)` is `0`, so that gives us that (and also means we don't have to divide by zero).

Hence the code necessary must do exactly that:

```
public static double harmonicSum(int i)
{
  if(i < 0)
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("i must be positive.");
  if(i == 0)
     return 0;
  return 1.0 / (double)i + harmonicSum(i - 1);
}
```

Since we've done your homework, try to work out how to do the same without recursion, and pros and cons for each.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is way beyond the factorial example that was used in class. Also why did you change the parameter to an int? I will try it with more conventional loop like a for or do/while.

Comment: I changed the parameter to an int, because that matches what you are doing; starting with an integer value and ending with a floating point value. Your basic problem has no meaningful answer for e.g. `2.5`.

Comment: And do really see if you can figure out how to re-write the same thing without recursion, turning recursive code into iterative and vice-versa is an important real-world skill, that many classes covering each don't go into. (Esp. since iterative tends to be the more performant with a language like Java and recursive the more performant - or only possible way - in functional languages, so there tends to be real advantages in being able to move between them).

Answer (score 0):

Issue is you are expecting 1/2 or 1/3 ....  will sometime be equal to 1 which never satisfies and hence you keep on repeating the recursive call and finally jvm gives up as StackOverflowException to you.

I believe you meant to decrement n2 value and then check for equality as 1. Anyways try this:

```
public static double recursiveUse(int n2) {

    if (n2 == 1)
        return 0.;
    return 1 / (double) n2 + recursiveUse(n2 - 1);
}
```

This will add 1/n2 + 1/(n2-1) as per your need and return back the result so you could add 1 to the result returned bu this method.

Comment: I think the code has the other problem - `if (n2 == 1)`. We shouldn't use `==` with floating-point in this case, should we?

Comment: @ikh i changed n2 variable to int instead of float.

Comment: If `n2 == 1` you should return `1` (or alternatively wait until `n2 == 0` and return `0`.

Comment: No See OP's final sysout. He is adding 1 there `System.out.print(1+(recursiveUse(n2)));`. which is why i wanted to avoid adding one here.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions and help. Like I said this is way beyond the scope of the factorial example used in class. I didn't even know that you could put stuff between the return and the recursive call.